# How to have A tags click when parent stops propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a popup effect, where there is a background shade element. The problem is that when I click `A` tags, the href does not trigger.

Here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="A" align="center">
    <div class="B">
        <a href="mailto:example@hotmail.com">LINK</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".A").click(function() {
    alert(1);
});
$(".B").click(function() {
      return false;
});
```

CSS

```
.A {
  background-color:green;
  height:100%;
}

.B {
  width:100px;
  background-color:cyan;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d1qb26td/3/

If you click the green part, I close the whole popup, i just put an alert one for now. However if you click the inner container part, nothing should happen, so I put a return false on the click event. However for the `A` tags within the inner container, I want them to still work, but the return false part is stopping it.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: While the click is inside `.B`, you won't be able to click on it. (At least not to trigger its function)

Comment: You must create a listener on the `<a>` tag. The click is heard on the link, but then bubbles up to .B and is halted there.

Comment: I can create a listener on the a tag, but then how would I invoke the href? It's a mailto link.

Comment: just do `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: where do I put that code?

Comment: @omega - Luis is correct. Replace `return false` with his suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `event.stopPropagation()`

```js
$(".A").click(function() {
    alert(1);
});
$(".B").click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.A {
  background-color:green;
  height:100%;
}

.B {
  width:100px;
  background-color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A" align="center">
    <div class="B">
        <a href="mailto:example@hotmail.com">LINK</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this also.

```
$(".B a").click(function() {
window.location = this.href;
    return false;
});
```